# Test if a user is in a country that can buy paid apps

Tags: android, billing

I want to refer users of an Android application to try out another app.  The other app is a paid app and I only want to refer them to the app if they could possibly purchase it.  How do I test if the user is in a country that supports purchasing paid apps through the play store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priced application are only available in [these](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/143779) countries. Get the country from user and match it from the list to find out if paid apps are supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not official. But you could use old [Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/). Completely not sure if it works.